# Redirects to another site

Tags: java, redirect, spark-java

Can I make redirect from current page to google.com (for example)?

I tried to use method *redirect* and *header* with **Location**.

Is it possible to somehow implement a redirect to another website, or only path (/page1 -> /page2)?

Comment: https://www.codingninjas.com/studio/library/page-redirection-in-jsp